# IsAuthenticated Staying false when cookie has been set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net identity core. I no everything is working OK cause I can create my user through my registration page and it appears in my tables fine. However the issue I am having is on login.

I am including my startup.cs main methods to see if anyone knows what I have missed for when i check the isAuthenticated attribute its always returning false.

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),b=>b.MigrationsAssembly("solitudeeccore")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddTransient<IMessageService, FileMessageService>();
            services.AddAuthentication(
           options => options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

}
```

I have placed this at the end of my Configure method in startup cs.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
            AuthenticationScheme = "CookieAuthentication",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,

            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseIdentity();
}
```

My Account Controller and this is how i intiate the variables.

```
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService; 

[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login");
            return View();
        }
        if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Confirm your email first");
            return View();
        }

        var passwordSignInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent: rememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (!passwordSignInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login");
            return View();
        }

        return Redirect("~/");
    }
```

My Actual Login page

```
 <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true"> Remember Me
                    <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="false" />

                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    </form>
```

It is after all this that this variable is staying false does anybody have any idea.

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>User @User.Identity.Name is signed in. <a href="/Account/Logout">Logout</a> </p>

}
else
{
    <p>No user is signed in.</p>
}
```

**Edit 2**
This is my complete startup methods now in quesiton after below comments and I still having the same result the user is not authenticated.

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),b=>b.MigrationsAssembly("solitudeeccore")));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddTransient<IMessageService, FileMessageService>();
        services.AddAuthentication();            
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();                
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


    }
```

Comment: The order of middlewares is important. If you place `UseIdentity()` after `UseMvc()` it will never be called, since Mvc middleware will handle it before it reaches it

Comment: How then is it registering the user ?

Comment: User registration isn't part of the middleware, that happens in your controller and they are handled by Mvc middleware. Also note, that it's not necessary to register your own cookie middleware, unless you need a different scheme. `UseIdentity` already registers multiple cookie auth middlewares, required for Identity authentication

Comment: Even with that moved up i recompiled it still the same result anything else I could be missing

Comment: @Tseng I made the changes see above but still same result bring back webforms this is a steep learning curve but using time off to further my knowledge See edit 2 in bold my complete startup methods for that

Comment: @Tseng its turns out my verify email link was not correct it now working as expected thank you for asistance if you put it in a proper answer I will award it .